# Pro Git 2nd Edition - prerequisites to generate book

Tags: git

It is about the book Pro Git, 2nd edition and instructions how to generate book from source:
https://github.com/progit/progit2

How to fulfill prerequisites `bundle install` `bundle exec` ?
What is `bundle` about ?

Are the bundle-base commands strings the same as what has been referred to by term `generating manually by Asciidoctor` ?

Comment: AFAIK `bundle install` is a ruby thing. Probably make sure ruby is installed, and `bundle` should install the rest?

Comment: See [tag:bundler]…